# Find function doesn't return the right value

Tags: c++, dictionary, enums

Is it not possible to fill a map like this:

```
void Spel::Fill( void )
{
    int buildslist[] = {3,3,2,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,2,3,3,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1};
    Building::buildings p;

    for( int i = Building::INDIGOK; i < Building::STADSHUIS; i++)
    {
        p = (Building::buildings) i;
        gebouwenMap[p] = buildslist[i];

    }
}
```

This gives all `0`. `Building::buildings` is an enum with some building names. The `buildslist` is a list of how many people could join that building.

Comment: What's the type of `(Building::buildings)` ?

Comment: enum buildings { house, werf}; so the map must be for example werf = 1

Comment: next time please: 1) use english variable names 2) describe the clasees more - no one can know what is Building, what returns INDIGOK, etc

Comment: We also need to see the definition of gebouwenMap.

Comment: Sorry, it was a dutch project that's why it's not in english. This is the definition of gebouwenMap map<Building::buildings,int> gebouwenMap;

Comment: A simple test seems to work fine for me. But you might want to change the loop condition; Now you will not get `Building::STADSHUIS` in the loop. Change to `i <= Building::STADSHUIS`.

Comment: Also, this loop only works because of the way old C-type enums work (in reality they are integer constants). New C++11 strongly typed enums can not be used this way.

Comment: O ok thanks. But when I print out the map it only gives me the numbers of the place in the enum, not let us say STADSHUIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is not enough code to give an actual answer. Please improve your question so that we can help you properly.

Second, the title is misleading "Find function doesn't return the right value". There is no "find" function and there is no "return value" because the only function you show returns `void`.

Now thet this is sorted out, let me try to help you:

```
    p = (Building::buildings) i;
```

This is a cast from int to enum. I think this is bad C++ (probably undefined as in might work for some compiler but not as a rule of thumb). You would have to use a switch here I think.

Please write code in English. Do you imagine if someone you work with is Japanese and would write the code with japanese variable names? Even if the project is in Dutch, write code in English including comments.

*EDIT:* You might want to use strings instead of an enum here.

Try using a `std::map<std::string, int>` to encode your building names instead of an enum, then use an `std::map::iterator` to iterate through it.

Comment: Yep sorry, next time I will program in english. The return function I use to get how many buildings there are in the map is this:int Spel::getAantalGebouw(Gebouw::gebouwen type) const
{
 return gebouwenMap.find(type)->second;
}